# Need to add stable HTML & CSS into jquery "ContentFlow"

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I ma helping someone out to make a web site but I cant find solution how to add HTML & CSS instead of images in the javascript "ContentFlow" it has been downloaded here: http://www.jacksasylum.eu/ContentFlow/

here you can see how it looks with html text:
 http://portfoliodummy.medienbayer.de/ContentFlow_mb_test/

as you can see when you move the blocs the text goes up and down! I have tried to add padding to it. not to assign font-size... but it wont work. I need to know if anyone has any idea or maybe solution. I know that images are the best way to go but he wants it to be with HTML.

Thank you for your Help

Comment: Your second link isn't working for me. It shows up with ellipses in the browser bar.

Comment: @Shpetim the background colours are working. So just add the CSS to whethever you set the background colour

Comment: the problem is with the text, as you can see when you move the blocks the text jumps around! I dont want it to jump around but I want it to resize properly with the blocks

Comment: The html and css are behaving correctly... Maybe generate images using js, so the dynamic content is preserved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.ContentFlow * {
margin: 5%; /*adjust the value as you prefer */
}

.ContentFlow .flow .item div.content {
overflow: hidden;
}
```

tested only on chrome/linux. :-)

This improves the situation. Not sure if further improvement is possible.

Comment: thinking about it... if you could add manually <BR /> in some way at every line it should be stable. Maybe you can in some way use javascript to force newlines with BR. It is complex, but probably doable. Good luck and thanks for accepting the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could use

```
.ContentFlow .flow .item div.content {
  overflow:hidden;
  white-space:nowrap;
}
```

Then do hard breaks <br /> on the content to ensure each item fits in the box.  There'll be some clipping on resize but you won't have a bounce.  You could probably automate where to put the breaks with a little javascript magic too.